# Creating a zoomable scatter chart of millions of points

Tags: graphs, math, macos

I want to create a scatter chart that plots millions of points from a [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file, and allows interactive zooming to explore the finer structure on different scales. I am not very familiar with programming, unfortunately, so something GUI-based would be amazing.

OS: Mac OS X

Data type: two columns of integer coordinates

Answer (score 1):

Well, a very simple way to do this would be to copy data to a spreadsheet program. [Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numbers_(spreadsheet)), [Excel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel), and [Google Sheets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Sheets) are three I am familiar with. These have the capability to make x-y scatter plots. Be sure to use scatter plot to be able to easily zoom scales. Load the data (paste) into two columns of a spreadsheet page. Then use the x-y scatter plot option to plot the data. Then to zoom in, just manually change the x-axis and/or y-axis. This is a very primitive way, but if you need something quick this will work.

Another method for the Mac are programs from SourceForge. Two projects I'm familiar with are [GNUPlot](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuplot/) and [SciDAVis](https://sourceforge.net/projects/scidavis/). Both of these are available for the Mac. SciDAVis is simpler and quicker to learn in my experience. But it is spreadsheet-based and may not do able to handle millions of points. I don't know, but it would be easy to find out. I'm confident GNUPlot can read millions of points.

Another possibility is [Veusz](https://veusz.github.io). It is advertised as a scientific plotting package. Instructions are found at the link I've included. It is GUI-driven.

If money is not a concern I suggest [Igor Pro](https://www.wavemetrics.com). It may handle all your points.

Comment: Excel can only handle 1,048,576 rows so maybe not enough for “millions”. I certainly wouldn’t use Excel for such large datasets. Veusz looks nice. I’d try that first.